# Regex matching CSS colors hex codes

Tags: css, ruby, regex

This should be easy...I'm trying to match 3 hex digits in a row in a css file with ruby. Here's what I've got..

```
File.open(ARGV[0], 'r') do |source|
  source.each { |line|
  puts line if line =~ /\h{3}/
}
end
```

This doesn't return anything back in a file that has several of such values. if I change line to be `line =~ /\h/` then virtually every line gets returned. I know I must be missing something basic but what is it?

EDIT. Here's some sample input. Valid hex colors of course can be three hex value combinations, but for now im just concerned with the six valued ones.

```
#captcha fieldset{border-top:1px solid #c0c0c0;border-bottom:1px solid#c0c0c0;margin:0;padding:10px}
#captcha legend{color:gray}
#captcha .divider{display:none}
#captcha .captcha_refresh{font-size: 9px;color:gray}
#captcha .captcha_other_options{padding-top:5px;font-size: 9px}
#captcha .recaptcha_text{font-size: 11px;line-height:16px}
#captcha .captcha_optout{font-size: 11px;padding:10px 0 5px}
#captcha #recaptcha_image{font-weight:bold;margin:10px 0 0 0}
#captcha #recaptcha_image a.recaptcha_audio_cant_hear_link{font-size: 9px;font-weight:normal}
#captcha .captcha_loading{border:0}
#captcha .captcha_image img{border:1px solid #c0c0c0}
#captcha .captcha_input input{direction:ltr;margin-top:4px;width:137px}
#captcha .captcha_input label{margin-right:4px}
.register #captcha .captcha_input label{color:#666;font-weight:bold}
#generic_dialog.captcha .generic_dialog_popup{width:340px}
```

Comment: Can we see some sample input?  `\h` will match `[a-fA-F\d]` so you know.

Comment: added. That's part of facebooks css I think...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this one?

```
/(?<=#)(?<!^)\h{3}/
```

With this variation if you want 3 or 6 characters...

```
/(?<=#)(?<!^)(\h{6}|\h{3})/
```

#### Console testing

```
1.9.3p392 :002 > css = "#captcha fieldset{border-top:1px solid #c0c0c0;border-bottom:1px solid#c0c0c0;margin:0;padding:10px}"
 => "#captcha fieldset{border-top:1px solid #c0c0c0;border-bottom:1px solid#c0c0c0;margin:0;padding:10px}"
1.9.3p392 :003 > css.scan(/(?<=#)(?<!^)(\h{6}|\h{3})/)
 => [["c0c0c0"], ["c0c0c0"]]
```

Comment: `css-colors.rb:19: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<=#)(?<!^)(\h{6}|\h{3})/`

ruby 1.8.7 if that matters

Comment: That was only the regex expression. I added the rest of the line.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, are you sure this method works on ruby..?

Comment: Sure, I ran it before posting. I updated my answer to include a console output.

Comment: Looks good, I think my problem is I have a bad ruby binary trying to execute, I cannot even run a plain ruby interpreter, I remember I had a very peculiar time setting this up...thank you.

Comment: yeah i confirmed it working on a different server. Gotta fix ruby on my own box. Thanks for the help.